# Singleton dictionary is empty, and I don't see why

Tags: objective-c, singleton, ios9, xcode8

I have an iOS app that matches incoming text fields to *standard* fields used to import records.  My problem is that a NSMutableDictionary that uses those fields is empty!  Here is the code that saves the mapping:

```
-(void)mapUserFields: (id) sender  {   //  move contents of each textField when user has finished entering it

    SingletonDictionary *sd = [SingletonDictionary sharedDictionary];

    UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)sender;  //  textfield contains the pointer to user's half of the equation
    int tagValue = (int)tf.tag;  //  get the tag value

    [sd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes setObject:tf.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tagValue]];  //  value found in textField id'd by tag

    NSLog(@"\nfield.text: %@  tagValue: %d  nsd.count: %d\n",tf.text, tagValue, sd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes.count);

}
```

This is the result of the NSLog:

> field.text: 1  tagValue: 38  nsd.count: 0

This is the definition of the singleton in the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryOfUserIndexes;
```

This is the code to initialize the singleton in the .m file:

```
//--  SingletonDictionaryOfUserIDs  --
+ (id) sharedDictionary  {

    static dispatch_once_t dispatchOncePredicate = 0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&dispatchOncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedObject;
}

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        dictionaryOfUserIndexes = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I believe my problem is because the *sd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes* is not initialized, but I am not sure if that's true, and if so, how to initialize it (I tried several different variants, all of which created build errors).  I looked on SO and Google, but found nothing that addresses this particular issue.  Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show how `dictionaryOfUserIndexes` is declared in your singleton class. And please format your code. You've posted far too many questions to be posting poorly formatted code.

Comment: Is that better re: formatting my code?  If not, I don't understand what you are referring to...please elaborate...  SD

Comment: What does `SingletonDictionary` inherit from?

Comment: First line in *mapUserFields*... now that I look at it, not sure that's correct either... I wrote this several years ago, and now looking back, can't remember why I did some of these things... was just learning about singletons then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things we could improve in this code, but the only thing *wrong* with it is the reference to `dictionaryOfUserIndexes` in the `init` method.  The code as posted wouldn't compile, unless: (a) you have a line like:

```
@synthesize dictionaryOfUserIndexes = dictionaryOfUserIndexes;
```

so that the backing variable is named without the default `_` prefix, or (b) you refer to the ivar with the default prefix, as in:

```
_dictionaryOfUserIndexes = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

The other way -- preferable in most every context except within an init method -- is to use the synthesized setter, like:

```
self.dictionaryOfUserIndexes = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

But with that change alone (so it will compile) your code runs fine, adds a value to the dictionary and logs an incremented count.